# Access third value of first key in dictionary python

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a dictionary where one key has multiple values - start_time_C, duration_pre_val, value_T. All are input from an excel sheet. 
Then I have sorted the dictionary.

```
pre_dict = {}
pre_dict.setdefault(rows,[]).append(start_time_C)
pre_dict.setdefault(rows,[]).append(duration_pre_val)
pre_dict.setdefault(rows,[]).append(value_T)
pre_dict_sorted = sorted(pre_dict.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Now, I want to compare a value (Column T of the excel sheet) with value_T. 
How do I access value_T from the dictionary?

Many thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use numpy structured arrays or pandas DataFrames for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this into two parts:

1. Reading in the spreadsheet

   I/O stuff like this is best handled with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html); if you'll be working with spreadsheets and other tabular data in Python, get acquainted with this package. You can do something like

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   #read the excel file into a pandas dataframe
   my_data = pd.read_excel('/your/path/filename.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
   ```
2. Accessing elements of the data, creating a dict

   Your spreadsheet's content is now in the pandas `DataFrame` "my_data". From here you can reference DataFrame elements like this

   ```
   #pandas: entire column
   my_data['value_T'] 
   #pandas: 2nd row, 0th column
   my_data.iloc[2, 0]
   ```

   and create Python data structures

   ```
   #create a dict from the dataframe
   my_dict = my_data.set_index(my_data.index).to_dict()
   #access the values associated with the 'value_T key of the dict
   my_dict['value_T']
   ```

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is that I have to sort the data in the dictionary and then compare. The values in the column is derived by a formula. So I used openpyxl to get data, manipulate it, then append it to dictionary.